# Upload File from Android App to Flask Server

Tags: android, python, file, http, flask

I'm trying to upload a file from an Android Application to a Flask server using logic I got from a previous StackOverfow question, but on the Flask side, request.values is empty, and the content-length also has no value.

Android Code

```
    android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
                System.out.println("Sending Message");
                String url = "http://localhost:5005/pin/123/upload";
                File file = new File(audioRecorder.getCurrentAudioPath());
                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

                    InputStreamEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity( new FileInputStream(file), -1);
                    entity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
                    entity.setContentEncoding("binary");
                    entity.setChunked(true);
                    post.setEntity(entity);
                    HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(post);
                    System.out.println(resp.getStatusLine());
                }

                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                 // System.err.println(e.printStackTrace());
                }
```

Flask Code

```
def uploadFiles(pin):
    print request.headers
    print str(request.values)
```

Which returns

```
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Length:
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: binary
Host: localhost:5005
Content-Type: binary/octet-stream

CombinedMultiDict([ImmutableMultiDict([]), ImmutableMultiDict([])])
```

Comment: The transfered files should be in `request.files` on flask side, is there something in that ?

Comment: No there isn't. Everything is empty on the Flask side. request.files, request.get_filelist(), request.data, request.get_data(), request.values all return an empty list.